# How to get these element to stay centered

Tags: html, css

I have these blocks of code that I want to stay center the entire time. But I am not sure how. I am hoping you guys could help me out here.
Here is the code

```css
main {
    width: 70%;
    float: left;
    clear: both;
    border-right: 1px solid #331a00;
}
main ul {
    margin-top: 1em;
    margin: auto;
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto
}
.index {
    float: left;
    border: 3px solid #b88f61;
    margin-top: 1em;
    margin-right: 2em;
    list-style: none;
}
main ul {
    margin-left: 3em
}
.index:hover {
    box-shadow: 1px 2px 3px 4px grey;
    border: 3px solid #331a00;
}
.index a div h3 {
    background-color: #331a00;
    padding: .5em;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: underline
}
.index a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
.index a div img {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    margin-bottom: -5px
}
#mobile_index {
    display: none;
}
#medusa {
    background-color: white;
    ;
}
#intro {
    width: 70%;
    margin: auto;
    margin-bottom: 4em;
    clear: both;
    font-size: 120%
}
#intro h4 {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 1em 0;
    font-size: 150%;
}
#intro h1 a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
#intro h1 {
    text-align: center;
}
/*ASIDE*/

aside figure {
    width: 100%
}
aside {
    width: 24%;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 1.5em;
}
aside h3 {
    font-family: "Times New Roman", serif;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-weight: bolder;
    padding-bottom: .5em;
    text-align: center;
}
.popular {
    display: block;
    background-color: #331a00;
    color: white;
    padding: .5em;
    margin-bottom: .3em;
    margin-right: .1em;
    margin-left: 0;
    font-weight: bold;
}
aside figure figcaption {
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #331a00;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: .5em 0;
    font-size: 1.2vw
}
form {
    width: 100%
}
input[type="submit"] {
    margin: auto
}
```

```html
<main>
   <h1 id="page_title">The Compendium of Greek Mythology</h1>
   <ul>
      <li class="index">
         <a href="Compendium Gods.html">
            <div>
               <img src="images/The Gods.jpg" alt="Gods">
               <h3>Gods</h3>
            </div>
         </a>
      </li>
      <li class="index">
         <a href="#" alt="Heroes">
            <div>
               <img src="images/The Heroes.JPG">
               <h3>Heroes</h3>
            </div>
         </a>
      </li>
      <li class="index">
         <a href="#">
            <div>
               <img src="images/The Monsters.png" id="medusa" alt="Monsters">
               <h3>Beasts</h3>
            </div>
         </a>
      </li>
      <li class="index">
         <a href="#">
            <div>
               <img src="images/The Titans.jpg" alt="The_Titans">
               <h3>Titans</h3>
            </div>
         </a>
      </li>
      <li class="index">
         <a href="#">
            <div>
               <img src="images/The Titans.jpg" alt="The_Giants">
               <h3>Giants</h3>
            </div>
         </a>
      </li>
      <li class="index">
         <a href="#">
            <div>
               <img src="images/The Gods.jpg" alt="The_Giants">
               <h3>Nymphs</h3>
            </div>
         </a>
      </li>
      <li class="index">
         <a href="#">
            <div>
               <img src="images/The Gods.jpg" alt="The_Giants">
               <h3>Constellations</h3>
            </div>
         </a>
      </li>
   </ul>
</main>
<aside>
   <div>
      <form method="get" action="http://www.google.com/search">
         <h3>Search the Compendium</h3>
         <input type="search" name="q" size="" maxlength="" placeholder="Google Search">
         <input type="hidden" name="domains" value="http://christiaanblom.coolpage.biz">
         <input type="hidden" name="sitesearch" value="http://christiaanblom.coolpage.biz"><br>
         <input type="submit" name="search" value="Search">
      </form>
   </div>
   <div>
      <h3>Popular</h3>
      <p class="popular">Zeus</p>
      <p class="popular">Poseidon</p>
      <p class="popular">Hercules</p>
      <p class="popular">Dragon</p>
      <p class="popular">Cyclops</p>
      <p class="popular">Ares</p>
      <p class="popular">Kronos</p>
      <p class="popular">Perseus</p>
      <p class="popular">Giants</p>
      <p class="popular">Gaia</p>
      <p class="popular">Oranos</p>
   </div>
</aside>
```

Right now, the .index  list items are staying on the left hand side of the main element. I've tried various things, but none of them worked out, which is why I am coming to you guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Remove padding and margin from `<ul>`, add `text-align:center;`
2. Remove the `float:left;` from `.index` and add `display:inline-block;`

```css
main {
    width: 70%;
    float: left;
    clear: both;
    border-right: 1px solid #331a00;
}
main ul {
    margin-top: 1em;
    margin: auto;
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
}
/* Remove the float: left; from .index and add display: inline-block; */
.index {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 3px solid #b88f61;
    margin-top: 1em; 
    margin-right: 2em;
    list-style: none;
}
/* Remove padding and margin from UL, add text-align:center; */
main ul {
    margin-left: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
.index:hover {
    box-shadow: 1px 2px 3px 4px grey;
    border: 3px solid #331a00;
}
.index a div h3 {
    background-color: #331a00;
    padding: .5em;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.index a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
.index a div img {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    margin-bottom: -5px
}
#mobile_index {
    display: none;
}
#medusa {
    background-color: white; /* Removed extra ; */
}
#intro { 
    width: 70%;
    margin: auto;
    margin-bottom: 4em;
    clear: both;
    font-size: 120%;
}
#intro h4 {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 1em 0;
    font-size: 150%;
}
#intro h1 a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
#intro h1 {
    text-align: center;
}


/*ASIDE*/
aside figure {
    width: 100%
}
aside {
    width: 24%;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 1.5em; 
}
aside h3 {
    font-family: "Times New Roman", serif;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-weight: bolder;
    padding-bottom: .5em;
    text-align: center;
}
.popular {
    display: block;
    background-color: #331a00;
    color: white;
    padding: .5em;
    margin-bottom: .3em;
    margin-right: .1em;
    margin-left: 0;
    font-weight: bold;
}
aside figure figcaption {
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #331a00;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: .5em 0;
    font-size: 1.2vw
}
form {
    width: 100%
}
input[type="submit"] {
    margin: auto
}
```

```html
<main>
   <h1 id="page_title">The Compendium of Greek Mythology</h1>
   <ul>
      <li class="index">
         <a href="Compendium Gods.html">
            <div>
               <img src="images/The Gods.jpg" alt="Gods">
               <h3>Gods</h3>
            </div>
         </a>
      </li>
      <li class="index">
         <a href="#" alt="Heroes">
            <div>
               <img src="images/The Heroes.JPG">
               <h3>Heroes</h3>
            </div>
         </a>
      </li>
      <li class="index">
         <a href="#">
            <div>
               <img src="images/The Monsters.png" id="medusa" alt="Monsters">
               <h3>Beasts</h3>
            </div>
         </a>
      </li>
      <li class="index">
         <a href="#">
            <div>
               <img src="images/The Titans.jpg" alt="The_Titans">
               <h3>Titans</h3>
            </div>
         </a>
      </li>
      <li class="index">
         <a href="#">
            <div>
               <img src="images/The Titans.jpg" alt="The_Giants">
               <h3>Giants</h3>
            </div>
         </a>
      </li>
      <li class="index">
         <a href="#">
            <div>
               <img src="images/The Gods.jpg" alt="The_Giants">
               <h3>Nymphs</h3>
            </div>
         </a>
      </li>
      <li class="index">
         <a href="#">
            <div>
               <img src="images/The Gods.jpg" alt="The_Giants">
               <h3>Constellations</h3>
            </div>
         </a>
      </li>
   </ul>
</main>
<aside>
   <div>
      <form method="get" action="http://www.google.com/search">
         <h3>Search the Compendium</h3>
         <input type="search" name="q" size="" maxlength="" placeholder="Google Search">
         <input type="hidden" name="domains" value="http://christiaanblom.coolpage.biz">
         <input type="hidden" name="sitesearch" value="http://christiaanblom.coolpage.biz"><br>
         <input type="submit" name="search" value="Search">
      </form>
   </div>
   <div>
      <h3>Popular</h3>
      <p class="popular">Zeus</p>
      <p class="popular">Poseidon</p>
      <p class="popular">Hercules</p>
      <p class="popular">Dragon</p>
      <p class="popular">Cyclops</p>
      <p class="popular">Ares</p>
      <p class="popular">Kronos</p>
      <p class="popular">Perseus</p>
      <p class="popular">Giants</p>
      <p class="popular">Gaia</p>
      <p class="popular">Oranos</p>
   </div>
</aside>
```